# change of Basis $\beta$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension n and $F:V\to V$ be a linear map. Suppose $\beta$ is the basis of $V$ and $N$ is an invertible matrix. Show that there exist a basis $\beta'$ such that $M_{\beta'}^{\beta'}=N^{-1}~M_{\beta}^{\beta}~N$.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: This is the formula for the change of basis from $\beta$ to $\beta'$, where $N$ is the change of basis matrix. So this is just asking whether any invertible matrix can be a change of basis matrix. When you have shown this obvious fact, please take the time to answer your own question below.

Comment: to show the existence of $\beta'$ do I have to construct it?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $M^{\beta'}_{\beta} = M^{\beta}_{\beta'} M^{\beta}_{\beta} M^{\beta'}_{\beta} = (M^{\beta'}_{\beta})^{-1} M^{\beta}_{\beta} M^{\beta'}_{\beta}$ and so a good guess would be to try and define $\beta'$ so that $M^{\beta'}_{\beta} = N$. Show that this is indeed possible are you are done.